# Generate all strings of length n from given letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-itertools

Given letters `a,b` and `n=3` I want to get the following strings :
`aaa,aab,aba,abb,bbb,bba,bab,baa`.

That is, I need to generate all strings of length n from the given letters 'a' and 'b'

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That's because 3**20 is too large a number. Your memory cannot hold such a list.

Comment: Have you tried this [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)?

Comment: Maybe that will help : ```>>> from itertools import permutations``` ```>>> perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('stack')]```

Comment: May I ask why do you want to do that?

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Other than the fact that you are allocating 100 GiByte of RAM, I don't see any problem with your code, so you really need to be more specific as to what your *actual* problem is.

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific, I have updated my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call works in theory, but the number of possible strings grows exponentially with `n`. For a pool of 3 letters and strings of length 20, that would make `3**20 = 3,486,784,401 ~ 3,5bn`. You can make a lazy generator though:

```
all_ = map(''.join, product('RPS', repeat=20))

>>> next(all_)
'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR'
>>> next(all_)
'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRP'
>>> next(all_)
'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRS'
>>> next(all_)
'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRPR'
>>> next(all_)
'RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRPP'
```